# How can you import code from the website codemyui.com?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been having a lot of trouble using this code from codemyui.com, and I'm not completely sure what to do.

src: https://gist.github.com/CodeMyUI/0ba729244a906a978b20d836c6b5d268

I copied the code for the javascript, html, and css file exactly, so there's no problems there. The main thing I think I messed up on was referencing javascript and the links to cloudflare / jquery. Here are the exact things I put.

```
 <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial=scale=1">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="syle.css">
    <title>Experimental Website</title>
</head>
```

And then, at the end of the body, I put in this code.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

I'm a bit new to coding so if anyone knows the answer thanks!

Comment: `syle.css` should be `style.css`?

Comment: Is your html file in the same directory as the script.js you are trying to reference?

Comment: @Frank can you answer this new problem?

Comment: Try use your browser's dev tool and see what's the error message. If you are using Chrome press F12 and refresh, see what's the error message in Console tab. Without error message hard to tell what's the problem. As Liam said, script.js file should be in the same directory.